# mysql insert based on condition

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to insert some values in a table based on a condition. Basically I have 2 fields:

From and To

I need to insert the values in their range in increments of 11.

Suppose the following

From = 79090200
To = 79090233

So the following values would be saved:
79090200
79090211
79090222
79090233

I still a newbie so any help would mean a lot.

Comment: You don't do logic in MySQL. You do it in some of the myriad of scripting / compiled languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a range of numbers using UNION and insert based on that. Something like this:-

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeNumeric)
SELECT 79090200 + ((Units.i + Tens.i * 10 + Hundreds.i * 100) * 11) AS SomeNumber
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
HAVING SomeNumber BETWEEEN 79090200 AND 79090233
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below stored procedure to store these values in a table

```
DELIMITER $$
USE test$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_increment`$$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`.`sp_increment`()

    BEGIN


DECLARE start_val INT;
DECLARE end_val INT;

SET start_val=79090200;
SET end_val=79090233;

WHILE start_val <= end_val DO
    INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES(start_val);
    SET start_val = start_val + 11;
END WHILE;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can use below procedure to get values from a table-

```
DELIMITER $$
USE test$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_increment`$$

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`.`sp_increment`()

    BEGIN


 DECLARE s_val INT;
 DECLARE e_val INT;

SELECT st_val, end_val INTO @start_val, @end_val FROM my_val;

 SET s_val=@start_val;
 SET e_val=@end_val;

WHILE s_val <= e_val DO
    INSERT INTO increment_tbl VALUES(s_val);
    SET s_val = s_val + 11;
END WHILE;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This works great, the only issue is now I have to replace 79090200 and 79090233 with fields, which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: I have updated 2nd script as per your requirement, please check it.

Comment: If it helps you then you can accept it as answer, so that it can be helpful for others...